# Поиск строки в Java

Tags: java

Допустим есть строка: "основные HTML тэги также поддерживаются"
Нужно проверить содержится ли в строчке словосочетание "также поддерживаются"
обычный contains работает только с 1 словом

Comment: > обычный contains работает только с 1 словом

Кто вам сказал?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"основные HTML тэги также поддерживаются".contains("также поддерживаются")
```

должно работать, так как java не разбивает на слова, она работает с последовательностями, а пробел  такой же символ как и остальные.

Comment: Даже не должно, а обязано работать.

Comment: добавлю, функция возвращает "-1" если ничего не найдено, или позицию найденого вхождения:

        "здесь мы ищем что-то".indexOf ( "что-то" );